# Jetson TK1 boot issues

Tags: linux, embedded, nvidia

Received my Jetson TK1 yesterday. After unboxing it and configuring the Linux GUI, rebooting the device with a mouse (cordless) attached to its USB 3.0 port takes it to some sort of Command line page where it probably loads some files and then the screen starts printing " [ . ] ". Nothing happens beyond that until I restart the board without any USB peripheral and then the device boots into the normal Linux GUI. Unable to figure out what's wrong with my board and why is it not working properly.

P.S.: Connecting the monitor via HDMI after switching on the device gives no visual output, just a blank screen. Is it possible to connect the device via network adapter for remote access even it the screen is running blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure you are not using serial console. Please check your `/boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf` and the "`console=`" line. If you have such a line, please remove it. It's blocking the HDMI output according to our testing.